# Fail to check files integrity

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a quick Python script to migrate files from one directory to another. Everything works out perfectly except for the part where I have to compare the filenames and checksum. I stored the file in both locations, that is, /root/src/file1 and /root/dst/file1.

So when I ran for filenames compare, it failed to match the file since it included the whole filepath. md5Srt is a dict that stores files and checksum.

Is there a way that I can compare the filenames without using the whole filepath?

```
for key in md5Srt.keys():
    if key in md5Dst:
        print "keys match " + key
        print '\ncomparing the values of files\n'
        if md5Srt[key] == md5Dst[key]:
            print md5Srt[key]
            print md5Dst[key]
            print "files match\n"
            print "checking the next pair"
        else:
            print "values of files don't match"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a bunch of files in a directory you can just use `os.path.basename`:

```
import os
>>> dst = os.path.basename('/root/dst/file1.file')
>>> src =  os.path.basename('/root/src/file1.file')
>>> dst
'file1.file'
>>> src
'file1.file'
>>> dst == src
True
```

If you are dealing with subdirectories you would need to know the base src and dst directories and then remove them from the beginning of each path:

```
>>> src = '/root/src'
>>> dst = '/root/dst'
>>> src_file = '/root/src/dir1/file1.file'
>>> dst_file = '/root/dst/dir1/file1.file'
>>> os.path.relpath(src_file, src)
'dir1/file1.file'
>>> os.path.relpath(dst_file, dst)
'dir1/file1.file'
>>> os.path.relpath(src_file, src) == os.path.relpath(dst_file, dst)
True
```

If you combine this with your function you get:

```
import os

src = '/root/src'
dst = '/root/dst'
for key, src_file in md5Srt.iteritems():
    dst_file = md5Dst.get(key)
    if dst_file is None:
        print 'The destination is missing %s' src_file
        continue

    print "keys match " + key
    print '\ncomparing the values of files\n'
    if  os.path.relpath(src_file, src) == os.path.relpath(dst_file, dst)
            print srcFile
            print dst_file
            print "files match\n"
            print "checking the next pair"
    else:
            print "values of files don't match"
```

I think you should rethink trying to compare files by finding a file in `dst` that has the same md5sum as a file in `src`. If a file is renamed or there are two files with the same hash you may end up with directories that are not exactly the same. A better approach would be to compare filenames first, and then check md5sums if there is a file that is in both `src` and `dst`.

Here is what that might look like:

```
import os

src_dir = '/root/src'
dst_dir = '/root/dst'

# reverse the dictionaries, hopefully you would create these dictionaries 
# to begin with. A single file can only have one md5sum, but the same md5Sum can 
# match multiple files
src_file_hashes = dict((os.path.relpath(v, src_dir), k) for k, v in md5Srt)
dst_file_hashes = dict((os.path.relpath(v, dst_dir), k) for k, v in md5Dst)

for src_file, src_hash in src_file_hashes.iteritems():
    dst_hash = dst_file_hashes.get(src_file)

    src_path = os.path.join(src_dir, src_file)
    dst_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, dst_file)

    if dst_hash is None:
        print 'The destination file %s is missing ' % dst_path
        continue

    if  src_hash == dst_hash:
        print '%s matches %s and %s' % (src_hash, src_path, dst_path)
    else:
        print '%s and %s have different hashes' % (src_path, dst_path)
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, it works...i have another question :) .... How about when i have more than one file in src and dst directory.  for example: /root/src/* & /root/dst/* (file1,file2,file3,cat..etc) your method above clearly extract a filename but i can't figure out how to extract multiple files.

Comment: I've been trying to use the second approach which is compares filenames first, then checksum on both src and dst.  However, it failed right away as i tried to compares filenames due to the whole filepath.  I wish i can post my codes here but it's too long :(

Comment: What about the code I just posted? That should check things the other way.